# Insert a row in DataGrid control

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I've got a standard ASP.NET 4.0 DataGrid control, it's declared like this:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="gridIssues" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnItemDataBound="gridIssues_ItemDataBound" UseAccessibleHeader="true" ShowFooter="true">
```

I need to insert another row with the "More tickets" button at the bottom when count of rows exceeds a certain number (see screenshot).

[http://dl.dropbox.com/u/347209/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-18%20at%206.45.53%20PM.png http://dl.dropbox.com/u/347209/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-18%20at%206.45.53%20PM.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/347209/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-18%20at%206.45.53%20PM.png)

The preferred way to do this is to inject html like `<tr><td colspan='%columns_count%'></td></tr>` on the server side somehow. I can do this on the client side with JavaScript, but this solution is not flexible enough for me.

Comment: Why you are using DataGrid,it's not recommended from Microsoft,instead  of, you can use GridView.. it's more powerful.

Comment: It's sort of legacy code and it would take a lot of effort to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

With databound controls, you should add rows to the datasource and then rebind. You can't easily add html directly.